# How do I make noodles greasy?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

The Internets are great for healthy and fresh and refined. Today I need help being none of those things. I am trying to satisfy my partner's craving for cheap, greasy chicken lo mein. I know how to make chicken lo mein. The Internet is full of recipes that "aren't greasy like takeout" or "healthier and fresher!"

But what if I don't want healthy and fresh?

**Does anyone have any suggestions for preparing egg noodles (or lo mein in particular) so the results are cheap-Chinese-restaurant-style greasy?**

It's not just more oil, though it might be the type of oil. I suspect it also has something to do with the order and length of cooking the noodles vs the vegetables and meat. I think the vegetables also have to be slightly overcooked. In case it matters, I don't have a wok.

Comment: Your question suggests you have already tried to simply be more generous with oil?

Comment: I have. It makes it more oily, not more greasy. It's not being absorbed.

Comment: Interesting question, I'm curious to see if there are good answers as I like that style of noodles too.

Comment: Most Chinese cookery uses neutral oil, with a high smoke point, for wok cookery.  What is your process?  Are you tossing cooked noodles in a pan that contains condiments (+ oil)?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/panda-express-style-chow-mein

Comment: FYI, I just talked to a local Chinese grocer who suggested corn starch might be part of the equation.

Comment: Corn starch is the basic 'shiny sauce' ingredient for Chinese take-away. It doesn't add 'greasy' though it does kind of homogenise the sauce in an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you starting with fresh noodles or dried?

Fresh are already 'greasier' than dried, so it may be a case of letting dried ones cool in the colander after their soak, in a good coating of oil, then adding towards the end of cooking as normal, just to re-heat.

One would imagine a take-away are not starting each portion of noodles from dried for every single order. They're already prepped & oiled so they don't stick.